# Why do (1),(2) and (3) hold?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D}),D<0$ $$F(p^m)=\sum_{\lambda \ mod \ p^m}e^{2\pi i \frac{ \lambda \overline \lambda}{p^m}}$$, where $p$ is a prime number. If $p$ splits in $K$ into two prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$,$\mathfrak{p}'$  then one can choose a number $x \in K$ with $\mathfrak{p}|x$ but $\mathfrak{p}'$ does not divide $x$. By this one gets a complete system of representatives mod $p$ $$xn_1+\overline xn_2,  \ \ (1)$$ where $n_1$ goes through a complete system of representatives mod $\mathfrak{p}'$ and $n_2$ goes through a complete system of representatives mod $\mathfrak{p}.$

Since $$Norm(xn_1+\overline xn_2)\equiv (\overline x^2+x^2)n_1n_2 (mod \ p) \ \  (2)$$ and $(x^2+\overline x^2,p)=1$ $$F(p)=\sum_{n_1n_2 \ mod \ p}e^{2\pi i \frac{ n_1n_2}{p}}=p. \ \ (3)$$

Could one explain me how to get (1),(2) and (3) ?

Thanks for the help.